# How to maintain the cursor position after inserting a new text javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an emoji picker and a textarea. When the user picks an emoji it should be inserted where the cursor currently is located. I need to maintain the cursor position so that the user can add more emojis where the cursor was before.

I can able to place the emojis where the cursor is located, But not able to maintain the cursor after the emoji is inserted.it should ideally be placed next after the character is inserted.

So far I have this

```
addEmoji (emoji) {
            const textarea = this.$refs.textarea
            const cursorPosition = textarea.selectionEnd
            const start = this.content.substring(0, textarea.selectionStart)
            const end = this.content.substring(textarea.selectionStart)
            const text = start + emoji.native + end
            this.content=text;
            textarea.focus()
            this.$nextTick(() => {
                textarea.selectionEnd = cursorPosition + emoji.native.length
            })
        }
```

This is a Vue js snippet. Please Help.

Comment: Check example: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-hofstadter-zp1ks?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, for some reasons that didn't work for me

Comment: What exactly didn't work ?

Comment: code inside `$nextTick`

Comment: I use setTimeout instead and that works for me

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I fix this myself, Posting an answer,so it may help someone facing the same issue

```
addEmoji (emoji) {
            const textarea = this.$refs.contenteditor
            const cursorPosition = textarea.selectionEnd
            const start = this.content.substring(0, textarea.selectionStart)
            const end = this.content.substring(textarea.selectionStart)
            const text = start + emoji.native + end
            this.content=text;
            textarea.focus()
            setTimeout(() => {textarea.selectionStart=textarea.selectionEnd = cursorPosition + emoji.native.length},50);
            this.show_emoji_picker=false;
        },
```

For some reason, I can't make this work using `this.$nextTick`.so I use
`setTimeout` instead.The above code works fine for me in vue js.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way starting with user4206843 answer:

Textarea

```
<textarea ref="commentTextarea"></textarea>
```

Ref

```
const commentTextarea = ref();
```

Method

```
const emojiClick = (emoji) => {
  // insert emoji at cursor position
  const cursorPosition = commentTextarea.value.selectionStart;
  const text = commentTextarea.value.value;
  const before = text.substring(0, cursorPosition);
  const after = text.substring(cursorPosition, text.length);
  commentTextarea.value.value = before + emoji + after;
  commentTextarea.value.focus();
};
```